# Odoo 11.0 make field unique

Tags: python, field, odoo-11

Can somebody explain how to make a field unique value? 
Like the invoice number, order number, ... each value must be unique.

I need this for the product internal_reference and contact reference too. 
I've been checking the parameters for these fields via Odoo Studio app, but I don't see anything how to make them unique.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
_sql_constraints = [
         ('Any_name', 'unique (your_field_name)','Your message!')]
```