# How to apply SQL Constrains in odoo 10?

Tags: sql, postgresql, odoo

I am setting up condition based on fields values included selection field as well.

```
    Field_1 = fields.Many2one('model_1_name')
    Field_2 = fields.Many2one('model_2_name')
    state = fields.Selection([('unregistered', 'Unregistered'), ('registered', 'Registered')], string="Status")
```

Applied `SQL Constraints` which is working

```
    _

    sql_constraints = [('unique_field','unique(Field_1,Field_2)',
        'custom message.'),
```

But I also need to include Selection Type field (`state`) with value(`registered`) in this SQL Constraints, How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to make Field_1,Field_2 unique only when state = registered??

Comment: Please tell us what your preferred constraint is. If not in SQL then in pseudo code or just as text.

Comment: You can use Model constrains https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/py/constraints.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Odoo 11.0 make field unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843819/odoo-11-0-make-field-unique)

Comment: view here http://glowodooerp.blogspot.com/2018/12/make-field-unique.html